# Filtering an array based on number of optional RegEx matches with priorities

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, sorting, filtering

Say I have an array of files, which have been matched from a bigger array of files with the expression in my code below. For simplicity I'll say the array of files is the following:

```
prefix_pt1_pt3_pt5_pt6
prefix_pt1_pt4_pt5_pt6
prefix_pt1_pt3_pt4_pt6
prefix_pt1_pt5_pt6
```

The file names are not necessarily sequential however.

I want to prioritise each capture group. The code I've come up with so far will only prioritise files until it doesn't match a capture group, so from the files above it will just select the first one. I want `prefix_pt1_pt3_pt4_pt6` to be the result of my function.

```
const parts = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6'];

const existsRegex = new RegExp(
  regexEscape(params.folder) +
  regexEscape(prefix) +
  parts.reduce((result, part) => result + `(_${regexEscape(part)})?`, '')
);
const validFiles = scanPath(existsRegex);

if (validFiles.length) {
  const chosenFile = validFiles.reduce((file, currentFile) => {
    const matches = currentFile.match(existsRegex);
    const killFrom = matches.indexOf(undefined);

    if (killFrom > 0) matches.length = killFrom;

    if (matches.length > file.length) return matches;
    return file;
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your group of files has the structure you mention and you want to retrieve the file with more parts in sequential order (part 1 has more priority than part 3), you could do something like the following:

1. Order the array of the chosenFiles using as criteria the number of the parts. In order to do that transform the name of the files into numbers (the numbers correspond to the concatenation of each number of each part).
2. Store the relation number-file in a dictionary.
3. Retrieve the name of the file from the dictionary, the key will be the first element in the ordered array.

```js
var chosenFiles = ['prefix_pt1_pt3_pt5_pt6',
    'prefix_pt1_pt4_pt5_pt6',
    'prefix_pt1_pt3_pt4_pt6',
    'prefix_pt1_pt5_pt6'
  ],
  dicc = {};

function getKey(arr) {
  return arr.join('');
}

function addEntry(file, index) {
  var numberArr = file.replace(/\D+/g, '-').split('-').splice(1).map(Number);
  dicc[getKey(numberArr)] = file;
  return numberArr;
}

function sortByFileNumber(a, b) {
  var i = 0;
  while (a[i] && b[i] && a[i] >= b[i++]) {}
  return a === b ? 0 : a[i] ? -1 : 1;
}

function pickFirst(arr) {
  return dicc[getKey(arr[0])];
}

var chosenFile = pickFirst(chosenFiles
  .map(addEntry)
  .sort(sortByFileNumber));

console.log(chosenFile);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I wasn't clear enough with my original question as the file parts are not necessarily sequential. The order/priority of them is already correct in the array used to build the RegExp though (`parts`), so hopefully what you've given me will help me find a solution.

Comment: Well, my whole idea was exactly that, give you an idea of how to solve the problem. It is difficult (sometimes impossible) to give an accurate answer (most of the times, the question only points out part of the problem). Please, consider marking my answer as the answer to your question if it leads you to the solution of the problem. Thanks :)